# Auto-indentation for Meteor/spacebars

Tags: indentation, web-mode

How do I get Emacs to auto-indent Spacebars blocks when coding with Meteor? Right now, Emacs automatically does this:

```
{{#each player}}
{{name}}
{{/each}}
```

instead of this:

```
{{#each player}}
    {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

Failing that, can I stop Emacs from deleting my indentation when I hit return? If I manually add indentation so that the code looks like the second example above, then hit return after {{name}}, it deletes the indentation so it looks like the first example.

Right now I’m using Emacs 25.2.2. I just use the basic GNU Emacs that I installed in Ubuntu 18.04, so I guess Vanilla Emacs. The major mode when I open html files is HTML.

I got a suggestion [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/spacebars-indentation-in-emacs/53220/4) to use web-mode.el, but I couldn't figure out how to set it up for Meteor.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Find yourself a `meteor-mode` and if all else fails, there's always `fundamental-mode`.  But clearly using `html-mode` if you're not editing html won't lead to good results.

Comment: @Stefan your comment seems to be assuming that I understood modes, even though that lack of understanding was a big part of the problem. It would have been more helpful to share something like the Emacs Manual page on major modes: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html#Major-Modes

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to use web-mode to solve my problem. For anyone interested, I explained what I did [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/spacebars-indentation-in-emacs/53220/8).